# Import CSV with Dynamic Columns

Tags: filehelpers

My Vendor is providing a CSV file where columns (names included on first line) are dynamic - meaning they will only appear if there is data in them and there is no guarantee on the order the columns will be provided

I am looking to understand the best approach to take to import such a horrible file.

Using the FileHelpers.net and optional fields.. but the issue with this is that the column orders can change

Comment: can you add some code

Comment: When you parse a CSV you generally starts by the header (titles). You can easily know what are the indexes and what is present or not. Once you know what you have and on what index, I don't see any more problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a FileHelpers class on the fly, then use that with the engine to import the CSV.  If you import as a DataTable, you would then be able to check if a column exists and populate your database using that or doing whatever you need to with this columns.